# Typescript does not load array declared outside a function. Please suggest

Tags: typescript

making http request and interpreting the response. The response contains and array of objects which is not getting loaded within the function.

```
Notes:- making http request.

public getRequest(): void {
    let bdoNamesArray: BdoName[];
    bdoNamesArray = [];

    this.http.get<BdoName[]>(this.bdoNamesUrl, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'})
      .subscribe((data: HttpResponse<BdoName[]>) => {
            let vjyArray: BdoName[];
            vjyArray = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
                  const obj = new BdoName();
                  obj.emplid = data.body[i].emplid;
                  obj.name = data.body[i].name;
                  vjyArray.push(obj); }
          console.log(vjyArray); // Array loaded from http-response
          bdoNamesArray.concat(vjyArray); // not loaded
          },
        error => {
          console.log('error on sub');
        },
        () => {
          console.log('sub completed');
        }
    );
    console.log(bdoNamesArray); // Emtpy array !!
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem and don't circumvent requirements.

Comment: You are filling the `bdoNamesArray` via a network request, which is asynchronous, but you are logging the array synchronously. So you are logging it before you have received any data, which is why it's empty.

Comment: I am logging bdoNamesArray on console after the http.get request call is complete. By this time, the subscription is also closed. As soon as i get http-respone vjyArray is loaded that i can see it on console. All i wanted is to copy that to another array - bdoNamesArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is empty when you are doing console.log at the end because that array is technically empty when it executes. This is due to the fact your code for manipulating the array runs *sometime in the future* and not directly after the subscription to the GET request.

For example; the execution of your code is something like this:

1. `let bdoNamesArray: BdoName[];
   bdoNamesArray = [];`
2. *An event triggered to GET data* `this.http.get<BdoName[]>(this.bdoNamesUrl, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'})`
3. You subscribe to this event by saying *whenever this event returns with my data do the following*

   ```
    let vjyArray: BdoName[];
       vjyArray = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
               const obj = new BdoName();
               obj.emplid = data.body[i].emplid;
               obj.name = data.body[i].name;
               vjyArray.push(obj); 
   }
   console.log(vjyArray); 
   // ...
   ```
4. It continues and executes `console.log(bdoNamesArray);` and you notice that it is an empty array.

   ***Sometime in the future:*** Your bdoNamesArray is populated by the logic you put in step 3

So your code is running *asynchronously* and therefore you will need to develop your logic into whatever you're doing within the callback of that asynchronous call.

One way to resolve this is to return the observable itself and let the caller decide the logic for the result.

Example (assuming that this.http.get() returns an observable):

```
public getRequest(): Observable<any> {
    let bdoNamesArray: BdoName[];
    bdoNamesArray = [];

    let result = this.http.get<BdoName[]>(this.bdoNamesUrl, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'});

    return result;
}
```

Another way could be that you have another callback function:

```
public getRequest(): void {
    let bdoNamesArray: BdoName[];
    bdoNamesArray = [];

    this.http.get<BdoName[]>(this.bdoNamesUrl, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'})
      .subscribe((data: HttpResponse<BdoName[]>) => {
            doStuff(data);
          },
          //...
}
```

Comment: Please read the updated line of code with comment "// not loaded".

Comment: Again, you will not be able to do this because the variable is outside of the subscribed event. You must do whatever it is you're doing within the callback function of the subscription. If you look at the order I wrote above, the concatenation doesn't happen before you console log it at the end.

Comment: "doStuff" does not work the way you are expecting. please read my comments.

Comment: I did read your comments. You will need to manipulate the data directly within the scope of the subscription. When you try to assign and use the variable outside of the scope, it has not yet been initialized as the initialization logic runs asynchronously. Please re-read my answer and let me know if something is unclear

Comment: I get an array of "objects" in the HTTP-response when i do "subscribe". But, I need to extract just the "name" property and load those into another array which is being used to get a drop-down list in view. How can i do this within the scope of subscription ?

Comment: You can use the map operator from rxjs to get the objects into a specific type you want and then return the Observable<YourType> to the caller, so that the caller can then subscribe to and decide what to do with it.